# Azure Active Directory Object Permissions

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I have an Azure Active Directory Application (and associated Service Principal). That Service Principal needs to be able to add and remove members from an Azure Active Directory Group...so I have added Read and write directory data under Application Permissions:

[image]

And I have code that uses the Client ID and Client Secret to get an Authentication Token an perform these operations using the Azure Graph API.

However, this permission is far too broad. I need the Application/Service Principal to only have the ability to add and remove members from specific groups (not all)...and not the ability to perform other types of operations.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a preview feature that partly fits your requirement: "Group.ReadWrite.All". It lets your principal create and update groups and their navigation properties (incl. members). It does not however reduce the permissions to modify only certain groups.

AAD permission scopes are described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-permission-scopes

Preview features may be subject to change and you'll have to agree to reduced service terms etc.: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/preview/

Comment: I'm using Azure AD security groups for permission management for an application. In non prod deployments of the application, developers should be free to add and remove users from these groups. In prod deployments, developers should not be able to add and remove users from these groups. There is one set of groups for prod and another for non prod. It sounds like Azure isn't suitable for such a scenario, correct?

Comment: Yes - I don't think that will be possible. Maybe you can use two separate ADs? In Azure you can create multiple ADs, and they will have separate tenentIDs, separate users, groups, apps, permissions and credentials. For development that might be safer anyway. You could then have some sets (for different scenarios) of users and groups, that you create/delete through the API for testing purposes, and your devs can have free reign in that second AD. You could even use it for automated tests.

Comment: How would I get users (which are sync'd to our local domain and authenticate through MSOL and ADFS) to be able to log in to our app? I can't set up a whole second directory integration with our local DCs...